# "-r requires -f as well" error on logcat but I am passing -f

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to run logcat on a kitkat phone and I'm getting an error, here is the command and output:

```
shell@falcon_cdma:/sdcard/Download $ logcat -n 2 -r 4096 -f "test.log"     
-r requires -f as well
Usage: logcat [options] [filterspecs]
options include:
```

So as you can see I'm passing "test.log" as the file name. I've tried without quotes, and absolute path and I continue to get that error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command I put on my question doesn't work but this one works:

```
logcat -n 2 -f "test.log" -r 4096
```

So basically `-r` has to come after `-f`.